# Problem to write long lines in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I have defined a PS1 prompt multi-line in my server with Ubuntu 11.04.
The problem occurs when I write a long command, the line cuts before the end of terminal and it continues at beginning the same line:
[image: screen capture 1]

But if I continue writing the line ends at the end of window and it continues in next line, as expected:
[image: screen capture 2]

And if I press `Home` key the cursor goes to the line above the first line.

I connect to server with SSH in a gnome-terminal.

The PS1 line in /etc/bash.bashrc is:

```
[ $UID -eq "0" ] && PS1="\e[31m┏━\e[42m┅◉ \e[37m\d ⌚ \t \e[31m┅\e[0m\e[31m━━\e[42m┅◈ \e[37m\H \e[0m\n\e[31m┣\e[0m \w (\e[36m\$(ls -1 | wc -l) fichero/s\e[0m) \n\e[31m┗\e[45m┅◉\e[1;37m \u \e[0m\e[31m━► " || PS1="┏━\e[44m┅◉ \e[37m\d ⌚ \t ┅\e[0m━━\e[44m┅◈ \e[37m \e[0m\n┣━━\e[42m┅◉ kernel: \e[37m$(uname -r) ┅\e[0m━━\e[42m┅◈ uptime: \e[37m$(date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%a %d %b %R") \e[0m\n┣ \w (\e[36m\$(ls -1 | wc -l) fichero/s\e[0m) \n┗\e[46m┅◉\e[1;37m \u \e[0m━► "
```

Some of the environment variables:

```
$ env
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
LC_ALL=
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_COLLATE=C
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
SHLVL=1
LESS=-Rsw
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does this occur with the normal `PS1` variable?

Comment: It's the PS1 that's the problem. When I try it here, I get the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I fixed it for you :

Here the first one :

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]┏━\[\e[42m\]┅◉ \[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[42m\]\d ⌚ \t \[\e[0;31m\]┅\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;31m\]━━\[\e[42m\]┅◈ \[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[42m\]\H \[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[0;31m\]┣\[\e[0m\] \w (\[\e[36m\]$(ls -1 | wc -l) fichero/s\[\e[0m\]) \n\[\e[0;31m\]┗\[\e[45m\]┅◉\[\e[1;37m\]\[\e[45m\] \u \[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;31m\]━► '
```

And the second one :

```
PS1='┏━\[\e[44m\]┅◉ \[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[44m\]\d ⌚ \t ┅\[\e[0m\]━━\[\e[44m\]┅◈ \[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[44m\] \[\e[0m\]\n┣━━\[\e[42m\]┅◉ kernel: \[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[42m\]$(uname -r) ┅\[\e[0m\]━━\[\e[42m\]┅◈ uptime: \[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[42m\]$(date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%a %d %b %R") \[\e[0m\]\n┣ \w (\[\e[0;36m\]$(ls -1 | wc -l) fichero/s\[\e[0m\]) \n┗\[\e[46m\]┅◉\[\e[1;37m\] \u \[\e[0m\]━► '
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that it was necessary to enclose the color codes between brackets.